# Easy way to read keys and values from text file on web server?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I was wondering, is there a file format that allows you to store keys and values, and some api that lets you read said file from a web server into a `NSDictionary` easily? I'm just trying to store 5 or so values associated with keys in a file on the web, so looking for something simple.

I know how to read a simple text file into an `NSString`, but I was wondering if there is something that lets me do what I described above easily / more efficiently without having to manually prepare the file myself and then write the code to tokenize it, etc.

Comment: JSON is what you're looking for

Comment: @kevin - It's just something really simply, a file with 5 or so keys and values related to them. Might there be something in cocoa or objective c that handles this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why people are suggesting JSON files rather than plist files. Plist files may be better suited in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format you need is json. The API you need is AFNetworking. Here is the sample which connect to a server and parse that json to NSDictionary.

```
//send son info to server
NSDictionary* json = @{
                           kUserTokenKey : [SOLUser currentUser].token,
                           kMarkerUserMarkPayIDKey : markerUserMark.objectID,
                           kCardMarkerPayIDKey : card.objectID,
                           kCardZipCodeKey: zipCode
                           };

//create a request url
    NSString* requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kSOLServicesURL,kSOLServicesMarkerPay];


//AFNetworking block to call server api  
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager POST:requestURL parameters:json success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        [manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];

//Recieving object from server and pass to json
        NSDictionary* obj = responseObject;

        if ([obj[kAPIStatusKey] isEqualToString:kAPIStatusSuccessKey]) {
            if (completion) completion(nil);
        } else {
            NSError* error = [NSError errorWithMessage:obj[kAPIDataKey] code:0];
            if (completion) completion(error);
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        [manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];
        LBLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        if (completion) completion(error);
    }];
```